# How do I set up dual boot when Windows is already installed?

Tags: dual-boot

What would be the best way to dual boot Ubuntu and Windows? I already have Windows installed and I don't want to lose my files. I just want to tinker around with Ubuntu and see if it works for me! All the guides I've seen start out with Ubuntu installed or used Windows 7. Can someone give me a link to a good tutorial on how to do this?

Comment: Must not have looked, much. Most guides are based on Windows installed first. What version of Windows? UEFI or BIOS install & hardware? What vendor & model system as some need special settings. You need good backup of Windows, which you should be doing anyway.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI Shows Windows screens
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi & http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2147295

Comment: What have you found and what are you confused about? As you pointed out, there is a lot of information about this already. FYI: if you don't want to lose your files, make sure that you always have good backups.  Installing operating systems and manipulating partitions are not risk-free tasks. Things can go wrong, or you can make mistakes, especially if you aren't experienced with doing it.  When asking here, it's expected that you search and research before asking and share your research with us and tell us why what you found didn't work for you.

Comment: You can "Try Ubuntu" when booting from installation media.  This won't affect your installed system. You can also install Ubuntu in a VM like VirtualBox. These are both good ways to "tinker" with Ubuntu without affecting your currently installed OS.